What is the name of this part for our sectional couch?
The couch I purchased a while ago came with these metal "U-hooks" that hold the sectional pieces together. Over time, one of them bent, and was made worse when I tried to straighten it out.
I need to repair or replace them, but I'm not even sure if I am searching with the right keywords ("sectional connectors", "sectional hooks", "u hooks", etc.). I also reached out to the original manufacturer, but have had no luck in hearing back. Does anyone recognize this part and have a name or keyword for it?



Disagree that U-bolt is the right term...can you have a bolt without threads?  @Blake do you have a pic of the thing in place?  Presumably there's more than one, and they're not all FUBAR.

Technically this post is off topic as furniture repair. However, there's some crossover to other applications with bending steel rod. I make my own utility hangers, for example, using heavy wire or rod of aluminum or steel.

These are just proprietary connectors that aren't going to have a formal industry term. Straightening these probably won't resolve your problem because aluminum weakens with "work".
They're not U-bolts. Bolts have threads.  However, you may find U-bolts that have the perfect spread and wire diameter. If so, fantastic. Buy them and cut the legs to length if needed.
Otherwise, buy some metal rod and bend them up. A bench vice is really helpful here, but you can achieve the same end with two pairs of large locking pliers, or even a hole in a board and a hammer.
To avoid the same deformation you see now, consider mild steel instead of aluminum.  Be sure to sand or file any rough edges to avoid damaging your upholstery.
